# Create a folder with app.config file

Tags: c#, winforms, app-config

I want to create a Windows Folder the name of the folder will get it from a `TextBox.Text` that the user will fill in, but inside this folder it should also create automatically an **app.config**

This is what I got so far:

```
private void CreateNewCustomer()
{
    Directory.CreateDirectory(@"C:\Users\khaab\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ReadingXML\ReadingXML\bin\Debug\Customers\" + CustomerTextBox.Text);
    StreamWriter File = new StreamWriter(@"C:\Users\k.abdulrazak\Documents\visual studio 2015\Projects\ReadingXML\ReadingXML\bin\Debug\Customers\app.config");
    File.Close();
    MessageBox.Show("You have successfully added a customer", "Customer added", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: I think you should try to use `System.IO.File.Create(string)` instead of `StreamWriter` -- MSDN Link: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d62kzs03(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: @GlennFerrie Thanks for your reply, do you have an example, because I don't understand that as I am new with C#.

Comment: @Khaab then find a tutorial or book on C#. Creating files is one of the most basic things. You can't do anything if you don't learn the basics. Check for example [How to: Write to a Text File](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bh11f1k.aspx) from the documentation's C# Programming Guide

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should have a variable that holds the root path whether to create the new folder and the app.config file, e.g., `string root = Environment.CurrentDirectory`. Then the CreateNewCustomer method would look like:

```
public void CreateNewCustomer()
{
    var di = Directory.CreateDirectory(Path.Combine(root, CustomerTextBox.Text));
    if (di.Exists)
    {
        var fs = File.Create(Path.Combine(di.FullName, "app.config"));
        fs.Close();
        MessageBox.Show("You have successfully added a customer", "Customer added", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }     
}
```

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
public void SubmitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
    var name = CustomerTextBox.Text
    if (String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(name)) 
    {
          MessageBox.Show("Enter a customer name!");
          return;
    }
    var result = CreateNewCustomer(name);        

    if (result) 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("You have successfully added a customer", "Customer added", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    } 
    else 
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Something went wrong.", "Customer add failed", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
    }
}


private bool CreateNewCustomer(string customerName)
{
    var result = true;

    try 
    {
        var basepath = System.IO.Path.Combine(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory, "Customers");
        var custPath = System.IO.Path.Combine(basepath, customerName);
        var appconfigpath = System.IO.Path.Combine(custPath, "app.config");

        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(custPath)) 
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(custPath);
        }
        System.IO.File.Create(appconfigpath);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceError("Error creating customer folder: {0}", ex);
        result = false;
    }    

    return result;
}
```